# Delphi Indy http OPTIONS

Tags: delphi, indy, http-options-method

I'd like to use the HTTP Options

```
OPTIONS /MyURL/DoCmd HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://www.asite.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-request-method
```

What is the way to make this with Indy ?

```
FIdHttp.Options('http://' + FHost + ':' + IntToStr(FPort) + '/MyURL/DoCmd', AResponseContent);
```

What will happen if the OPTIONS is not implemented by the server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the way to make this with Indy ?

`TIdHTTP` in Indy 10 has 2 overloaded `Options()` methods:

```
procedure Options(AURL: string; AResponseContent: TStream); overload;

function Options(AURL: string
  {$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}; ADestEncoding: IIdTextEncoding = nil{$ENDIF}
  ): string; overload;
```

What `TIdHTTP` does not have is native properties for the `Origin` and `Access-Control-Request-...` headers.  However, you can use the `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders` property for those, eg:

```
FIdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Origin'] := 'http://www.asite.com';
FIdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Access-Control-Request-Method'] := ' POST';
FIdHttp.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Access-Control-Request-Headers'] := 'access-control-request-method';
FIdHttp.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;

Response := FIdHttp.Options('http://www.asite.com/MyURL/DoCmd');
or
FIdHttp.Options('http://www.asite.com/MyURL/DoCmd', AResponseContent);
```

> What will happen if the OPTIONS is not implemented by the server ?

The server will likely return an error code, which `TIdHTTP` will raise as an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception unless you enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property.

Comment: In Delphi Berlin, I have only procedure Options for Indy. It seem that with my serveur which is an "handmade server" : it raise me error with no message even if log of the serveur answer the informations for OPTIONS method

Comment: I have same problem with TNetHTTPRequest